# Powershell nested IF statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to do the following:

1. Check for a file in `src`

   - If that file is there copy it to `dst`
   - If that file is exists in the `dst`, continue
   - If that file isn't in the `dst`, do something
2. Continue on but do something else
3. Finish off and do something else

I'm struggling to understand how the nested IF statements should be structured

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems pretty straight given your requirements:

```
$src = "e:\temp"
$dst = "e:\temp2"
$filename = "test.txt"

# 1.Check for a file in src
if (Test-Path "$src\$filename")
{
    # 1.A If that file is there copy it to dst
    Copy-Item "$src\$filename" $dst

    if (!(Test-Path "$dst\$filename"))
    {
        # 1.C If that file isn't in the dst do something
    }
    #1.B If that file exists in the dst continue
}
else
{
    #2.Continue on but do something else
}

#3.Finish off and do something else
```